# ConstraintLayout handles not showing Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I just updated Android Studio to 3.4 after that the constraint layout handles are not showing in design view.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: By" constraint layout handles" to you mean your constraints between your views or what?

Comment: no there will be handles top, left, bottom, and right you can drag and constraint with other views

Comment: Check my answer below, maybe it can help you'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that your container (`ConstaintLayout`) is only `30 dp` height, Please select `match_parent`.

Once you have done that you can put your views inside it and constraint them to one another (and all that inside the container - the `ConstaintLayout`).